# ArrayFormula vs ImportRange отличия

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем отличие двух этих функций, если нужно импортировать данные из одной таблицы в другую? С учетом того, что обе таблицы в одном файле. Может быть есть какие-то подводные камни в случае с ArrayFormula так как он вроде как не для этого предназначен.

Comment: Наоборот, если все в одном, не нужно `ImportRange`, работайте с формулами массива (если действительно нужна "массивная" обработка, а не обычные формулы).

Comment: @vikttur Понял, ImportRange использовать ТОЛЬКО в том, случае, если импортировать нужно из другого файла, верно, исключений не бывает, верно?

Comment: Ну, не знаю... Зачем заказывать такси и ехать кругами 5 кварталов, если магазин в соседнем доме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ARRAYFORMULA

Отображает значения, полученные с помощью формулы массива, в нескольких строках и столбцах. Также позволяет использовать массивы в функциях, не предназначенных для этого. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=ru

## IMPORTRANGE

Импортирует диапазон ячеек из одной электронной таблицы в другую. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=ru

Это совершенно разные формулы. Иногда (но лучше никогда) используют обработку результатов `IMPORTRANGE` в `ARRAYFORMULA`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(...))
```

А если наоборот, то `ARRAYFORMULA` используют для конкатенации аргументов `IMPORTRANGE`. Но в общем случае функции делают совершенно разные вещи и друг для друга бесполезны.

```
=IMPORTRANGE(ARRAYFORMULA(...),ARRAYFORMULA(...))
```

Для вашей задачи используйте либо `ARRAYFORMULA`, либо ссылку на диапазон в фигурных скобках `={}`.